# Is it better to code style in a jsx file while using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, sass, components, frontend

When I create a ui component while using reactjs, I always code styles using sass or less and **integrate them in a .html** file after compilation. But someone tell me it's not better than **code them just in the .jsx file as an object**, but I think this way is not suit the w3c~! >_<

So which way is better while using reactjs?

Comment: That's primary an opinion based question and the answer is - it depends. I would encourage you to either read a few articles with different approaches how to style jsx file and make a decision based on the specific use-case you have.

Comment: You should read this for example http://jamesknelson.com/why-you-shouldnt-style-with-javascript/